# Incorrect syntax near '=' ... Error in .ashx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to retrieve an image from database & showing it to gridview.But It shows the  Error in .ashx file that

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    "select Image from ImageStore where ImageID=" + imageid, connection); 
SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader(); dr.Read(); 
context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);
```

> Incorrect syntax near '='

How to solve it

Comment: Can you share your code as it is too vague to answer presently!!

Comment: It's a database error...

Comment: -1 @VishalSuthar:- How can you be so sure without the code?

Comment: Yes...I am very much sure...Let's see...@RahulTripathi

Comment: I'm not mind reader who can read ur brain pls provide some code :)

Comment: To be able to help you, we need the code that is erroring within the .ashx file

Comment: @vishal- But sometimes it insert the image

Comment: SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Image from ImageStore where ImageID=" + imageid, connection);
              SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
              dr.Read();
              context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);

Comment: what is the value of `imageid`?  If it is empty or null, that would explain the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
if(imageid != null)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("
          select Image from ImageStore where ImageID=" + imageid, connection); 
    SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);
}
else
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("
          select Image from ImageStore where ImageID=0", connection); 
    SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();
    context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])dr[0]);
}
```

Comment: @ vishal..Thanks vishal.. this Code Works :)

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't posted the code, am assuming you use an .aspx file and you have already rendered gridview control and all. Make sure you have added image control using

`<asp:Image ID="imgPhoto" runat="server"
                ImageUrl =
               '<%#"ImageHttpHandler.ashx?ProductID="+Eval("ProductID")%>'/>`

HTTP handlers have access to the application context. This includes the requesting user’s identity (if known), application state, and session information. When an HTTP handler is requested, ASP.NET calls the ProcessRequest method of the appropriate handler. The code that you write in the handler’s ProcessRequest method creates a response, which is sent back to the requesting browser.

Use return stmt in the method of getting image as

```
        return (Byte[])dtProductsPhoto.Rows[0][0];
```

Make sure you have registered the handler in Web.config file using

```
  <httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*ImageHttpHandler.ashx"
                  type="GridView.ImageHttpHandler,GridView" />
```

Hope it works...